# Dropbox isn't running/is already running

Tags: 13.10, dropbox

whenever I start my computer, dropbox does not automatically start itself aswell. Furthermore, when I try to start it using the program launcher, nothing happens. I then tried the command line (*dropbox status*), which gives: *Dropbox isn't running!*

Naturally I want to start it using the command *dropbox start*, which returns:

```
Dropbox isn't running!
Dropbox is already running!
```

Odd! My current workaround is to delete the *.dropbox-dist* and *.dropbox* folders from ~/ and then do *dropbox start -i*, which starts the installer again and gives me access to my dropbox up to the point at which I have to restart my computer.

Any solution on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install dropbox as per dropbox site document ?

Comment: I went to dropbox.com, downloaded the *.deb file and installed it using dpkg, if that answers the question.

Comment: Your workaround worked for me.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this by installing dropbox using software-center or Type following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

This will integrate nautilus with dropbox. After that you don't need to check and run dropbox manually.

Comment: Alright, two restarts later it does seem to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Found this thread upon running into the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 (unsure of which dropbox build I'm using). I'm logging in via ssh and after copying some files to the remote ~/Dropbox/ folder, I found that they weren't syncing. That's when I tried to manually start dropbox:

```
dropbox start
```

and got the isn't running/is already running message. What seemed to work was checking if there was already a dropbox process:

```
ps aux | grep dropbox
```

Found there was indeed, so I killed it and then restarted dropbox:

```
kill <pid>
dropbox start
dropbox status
```

Comment: this temporarily resolved the issue with running Dropbox but dropbox did not function anyways. The accepted answer actually resolved my problem with dropbox syncing.